# hand question review about this pot

Tags: poker-theory

[image]

IN the pot, its already a flush then why the pot did not divided equally between me and the COntender.Why he able to took all the pot ?

Answer (score 0):

He has an ace-high flush, while you have a king-high flush. His hand beats yours and therefore you lose